# TensorFlow's perceptron gives unexplaineble output

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, perceptron

I'am new to TF: I took perceptron's code from this tutorial on MNIST(actually, its not necessary to follow this link) :https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

I wanted to remake those perceptron to a perceptron with 1 layer and linear activation function, to make it the most simpliest form of : output =w2(w1*x+b1)+b2. But this is what i get:

***Data:***

`X_train`: array([[ 10.],
       [ 10.],
       [ 11.],
       [  6.],
       [  8.],
       [  9.],
       [ 22.],
       [ 14.],
       [  6.],
       [  8.],
       [ 11.],
       [  9.],
       [ 13.],
       [  7.],
       [ 13.],
       [  7.],
       [ 13.],
       [ 11.]])

`y_train`: array([[ 44.5825],
       [ 53.99  ],
       [ 52.4475],
       [ 37.6   ],
       [ 38.6125],
       [ 39.5875],
       [ 43.07  ],
       [ 74.8575],
       [ 34.185 ],
       [ 38.61  ],
       [ 34.8175],
       [ 36.61  ],
       [ 34.0675],
       [ 37.67  ],
       [ 49.725 ],
       [ 79.4775],
       [ 50.41  ],
       [ 51.26  ]])

`X_test`: array([[  6.],
       [ 14.],
       [ 14.],
       [ 12.],
       [ 13.],
       [ 13.]])

`y_test`: array([[ 55.75  ],
       [ 33.035 ],
       [ 38.3275],
       [ 39.2825],
       [ 50.7325],
       [ 45.2575]])

***Parameters:***

```
learning_rate = 1
training_epochs = 1
display_step = 1 #maintaining variable
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])
```

***Perceptron model:***

```
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, output_0):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    output_o = out_layer #This variable is just needed to print result in session 
    return out_layer

output_0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, n_classes]))
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
```

***Let's build the graph:***

```
prediction = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, output)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction-y)) #MSE
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost) #Gives the smallest cost

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

***Finally, let's run the session:***

```
with tf.Session() as Sess:
    Sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        number_of_bathces = len(X_train)/batch_size    
        _, c = Sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: X_train, y: y_train})
        avg_cost += c/len(X_train)
        print(Sess.run(output_0))
        if epoch % display_step ==0:
            print("Epoch:", '%02d' % (epoch+1), "cost =", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization finished")
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(prediction,1), tf.arg_max(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x:X_test, y:y_test}))
```

***And now, we get the output:***

```
[[ 0.77995574]]
Epoch: 01 cost = 262.544189453
Optimization finished
Accuracy: 1.0
```

The most confusing thing is the output(first number)! It should be somewhere in range of [30; 50]! Please, explain me, where did i do wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is notably messy, so I've removed a lot of redundant pieces:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X_train =  np.array([[ 10.], [ 10.], [ 11.], [ 6.], [ 8.], [ 9.], [ 22.], [ 14.], [ 6.], [ 8.], [ 11.], [ 9.], [ 13.], [ 7.], [ 13.], [ 7.], [ 13.], [ 11.]])

y_train =  np.array([[ 44.5825], [ 53.99 ], [ 52.4475], [ 37.6 ], [ 38.6125], [ 39.5875], [ 43.07 ], [ 74.8575], [ 34.185 ], [ 38.61 ], [ 34.8175], [ 36.61 ], [ 34.0675], [ 37.67 ], [ 49.725 ], [ 79.4775], [ 50.41 ], [ 51.26 ]])

X_test = np.array([[ 6.], [ 14.], [ 14.], [ 12.], [ 13.], [ 13.]])

y_test =  np.array([[ 55.75 ], [ 33.035 ], [ 38.3275], [ 39.2825], [ 50.7325], [ 45.2575]])

learning_rate = 0.05
training_epochs = 10

n_classes = 1
n_hidden_1 = 5
n_hidden_2 = 5
n_input = 1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out_layer

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

prediction = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction - y)) #MSE
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost) #Gives the smallest cost

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: X_train, y: y_train})
        print("Epoch:", '%02d' % (epoch+1), "cost =", "{:.9f}".format(c))
    print("Optimization finished")

    print(sess.run(prediction, feed_dict = {x: X_test, y: y_test} ))
```

It seems to work now. I've got the following results:

```
Epoch: 01 cost = 1323.519653320
Epoch: 02 cost = 926.386840820
Epoch: 03 cost = 628.072326660
Epoch: 04 cost = 431.689270020
Epoch: 05 cost = 343.259063721
Epoch: 06 cost = 355.978668213
Epoch: 07 cost = 430.280548096
Epoch: 08 cost = 501.149414062
Epoch: 09 cost = 527.575683594
Epoch: 10 cost = 507.708007812
Optimization finished
[[ 30.79703712]
 [ 69.70319366]
 [ 69.70319366]
 [ 59.97665405]
 [ 64.83992004]
 [ 64.83992004]]
```

Results may vary due to random initialization of weights.

Couple of tips:

1. Use smaller learning rate
2. Train over several epochs to see the dynamics

Comment: Could you, please, explain, what exactly did the `from __future__ import print_function`?  Actually, you set a low training rate and 10 epochs. Isnt it the same as setting heigher training rate but a single epoch for a LINEAR MODEL?

Comment: from __future__ import print_function is for python3 print function compatibility.